# Backward compatible when using three optional parameters vs one optional parameters

Tags: c#, overloading, optional-parameters

Previously I had a method like this:

```cs
public void Test(string a, string b = null, int? c = null, string d = null)
```

After the redesign, we decided to group all the optional parameters to a class which like this:

```cs
public class TestOptions
{
    public TestOptions()
    {
    }

    public string b { get; set; }

    public int? c { get; set; }

    public string d { get; set; }
}
```

So the method internal implementation will not change but the signature will become:

```cs
public void Test(string a, TestOptions options = null)
```

My question is, since the first method with three optional parameters is already in use, if I want to add this new method now, how should I achieve backward compatibility by overloading?

Comment: Personally, I'd vote for a new method name: `public void Test2(string a, TestOptions options = null)`.  Test2() will [wrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function) the old Test().

Comment: No need for a new method name -- just create a new overload. You can have both `void Test(string a, string b, int? c, string d)` and `void Test(string a, TestOptions options = null)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether you care about *code compatibility* vs *binary compatibility*; the latter is usually mandatory (to not break compiled code), but the former can be a little more flexible.

You can't just add the new overload, because then `Test("abc")` is ambiguous and no longer compiles.

Edit: as canton7 notes: you could add a `Test(string a)` method to avoid *that* ambiguity, but: others remain (see below), and it further complicates the API surface.

If we only care about *binary* compatability, we can do:

```cs
public void Test(string a, string b, int? c, string d)
    => Test(a, new TestOptions { ... }); // forwarded
public void Test(string a, TestOptions options = null) { ... }
```

But this will break *code* compatibility, because the existing code `Test("abc", "def")` no longer compiles. We can't just make the *second* parameter mandatory, because if we do that, the existing code `Test("abc", c: 42)` no longer compiles.

---

If you care about the best code compatibility, honestly the best option is to *not make `options` optional*. For example:

```cs
public void Test(string a, string b, int? c, string d)
    => Test(a, new TestOptions { ... }); // forwarded
public void Test(string a, TestOptions options) { ... }
```

This solves *almost all problems* of code compatibility. There's still one edge case: `Test("abc", null)` - so: how much do you care about that?

Comment: You can also add `Test(string a)`, which resolves the ambiguity

Comment: @canton7 yes, that's an option - I'll edit it in with credit - but `Test("abc", null)` remains ambiguous

Comment: Right, but you can get around that with `Test(string a, string b, int? c, string d = null)` I think? Then `Test("abc")` resolves to the new overload, `Test("abc", null)` maps to the `TestOptions` overload, and anything with more parameters maps to the old overload. Unless there's code that does `Test("abc", c: 3)`...

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to method overload the second signature, something like this should do it:

```
public void Test(string a, TestOptions options = null) =>
    Test(a, options?.b, options?.c, options?.d);
```

However, I question your need for the extra class in modern C#. If it's a matter of conciseness and clarity (ie, you only ever need to provide the latter parameters and you provide all the other ones too), you could simply use named argument calling:

```
Test("meep", d: "moop");
```

Comment: now `Test("abc")` is ambiguous

Comment: Sure, but that's OP's fault for requesting those two specific signatures. The class version can easily be non-default, and you can also disambiguate it manually (`Test("meep", (TestOptions)null);`).

Answer (score 0):

You might change that `TestOptions` into a `struct`.  But you can't apply it as a nullable argument in your overload.

```
public struct TestOptions
{
    public string b { get; set; }

    public int? c { get; set; }

    public string d { get; set; }
}
```

Add an overload having such a non nullable struct argument

```
public static void Test(string a, TestOptions options)
{ }
```

With that in place there won't be ambiguity for the calls below.
Both will call the old/first `Test(string a, string b = null, int? c = null, string d = null)` method, preserving the initial intend as before this new overload was in place.

```
Test("ab");
Test("ab", null);
```